# SQL - Execute Procedure with Variable as Parameter

Tags: sql, variables, parameters, procedure

I've just learned how to create stored procedures in SQL (using SQL Server 2008). I'm wondering if it's possible to do this:

```
USE [SomeDB]
GO

DECLARE @var int = 3
GO

EXEC SomeProcedure @param = @var
GO
```

When I try this, it gives the error: "*Must declare the scalar variable "@var".*"

I'm basically trying to pass a variable as a parameter. There surely must be a way to do this?

Comment: Take the second GO statement out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The GO command separates SQL batches.   The second GO command causes the DECLARE statement variable to be dropped, since the EXEC starts a new batch of commands

```
USE [SomeDB]
GO

DECLARE @var int = 3
--  GO

EXEC SomeProcedure @param = @var
GO
```

Comment: Also worth noting that GO is not a compiler or query engine command - it's recognised by the T-SQL tools (and can be changed in the editor). http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx

Comment: No problem, the beauty of this site is having someone who has made the same silly mistakes LOL